# Unable to add dialog when press my own softkeyboard key

Tags: android

I get the following android exception when I try to open a dialog. when i am press my own SoftKeyboard key how can I fix this problem?

```
BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
com.example.android.softkeyboard.SoftKeyboard.diqalog(SoftKeyboard.java:759)
com.example.android.softkeyboard.SoftKeyboard.onKey(SoftKeyboard.java:526)
android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onModifiedTouchEvent(KeyboardView.java:1252)
```

Comment: final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};
mCurKeyboard=simleyKey;
mInputView.setKeyboard(mCurKeyboard);
mInputView.closing();
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
       builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).show();

Comment: give  formatted code in your question and You use TAb BAr?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you cannot present a dialog from a remote service, you can only do so from within a running `Activity`, that's why you're getting a `BadTokenException`. But there are solutions to this problem:

**1) Present an `Activity` with `Theme.Dialog` theme:**

```
<activity
      android:name="com.srgtuszy.activity"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
      />
```

And start the activity as a new task:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

This way, you'll get an activity which will look just like a dialog.

**2) Present an empty and transparent `Activity` and show an `AlertDialog` from within the activity**

Declare and start the activity in manifest just as before, but use a transparent theme:

```
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
```

In the activity, override the `onCreate()` method and don's call `setContentView()` and present the `AlertDialog`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     Context context = this;
     AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
     dialog.setTitle("Hello!");
     dialog.show();
}
```

This is a more hacky approach, but in this way you can show a dialog to the user without dismissing the input method, you can use to to present edit options for instance.

If you just want to notify the user about a certain event, consider using `Notifications`, they won't distract the user and pollute the UI.

Comment: hei, good answer, is there a way a result can be given back to the InpuntMethodService?