# New Activity dismissing keyboard in InputMethodService

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service, android-input-method

I'm writing a custom keyboard for Android and I'm using `InputMethodService` to handle all keyboard-related events.

On a certain event, I present an `Activity` with `Theme.Dialog` theme to the user, but when it's presented, it dismisses currently visible `KeyboardView` and I want the keyboard to stay visible under the running activity.
Is there a way to avoid dismissing the keyboard or maybe there are more efficient ways to present a dialog with a few buttons to the user from a running `Service`?

Activity declaration in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
  android:name=".EditActivity"
  android:label="@string/edit_title"
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
  />
```

The code used to present the activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks in advance!

//UPDATE

Everything works correctly and `KeyboardView` is brought back when the `Activity` is not transparent, so removing the theme declaration:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

fixes everything. So the question is, how to present a translucent `Activity` without dismissing the `KeyboardView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured out how to do it, here is my answer to a different question with the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13652456/285680